# Drupal 7 pathauto not working

Tags: drupal-7, pathauto

I am using pathauto module. I have saved the pattern "Pattern for all Basic page paths" as content/[node:title], however, I see that the basic page links from the header navigation open as http://localhost/drupal71/node/2 or http://localhost/drupal71/node/4 etc. I am using WAMP and the 'url rewriting' is checked. Should I edit the ".htaccess" file for this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting all aliases and rebuilding them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add "URL Path Settings" of the basic pages. Please check the attached scree shot.
[image]